# how to increment the quantity of a product in laravel session

Tags: laravel, session, shopping-cart, laravel-7

**my cart session is**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 123-XXL
            [prod_name] => Grey Shirt
            [prod_rate] => 2100
            [size] => XXL
            [qty] => 1
            [ind_tot] => 2100
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 134-XL
            [prod_name] => red_shirt
            [prod_rate] => 1800
            [size] => XL
            [qty] => 1
            [ind_tot] => 1800
        )
)
```

Now i tried to increment the **qty** value of the session by 1,

**my increment function is**

```
public function increment(Request $request){
        $id = $request->id;
        $rate = $request->rate;
        $qty = $request->qty;
        $ind_tot = $request->ind_tot;
        $input = $request->all();
        $qty_up = $qty+1;
        $ind_tot = $ind_tot+$rate;
        if(Session::has('cart_sess')){
            $cart = Session::get('cart_sess');
            foreach ($cart as $key => $value){
                if($cart[$key]['id'] == $id){
                    $cart = $cart->replace([$cart[$key]['qty'] => $qty_up, $cart[$key]['ind_tot'] => $ind_tot]);
                    Session::set('cart_sess', $cart);
                }
            }
        }
        return response()->json($qty_up, 200);
    }
```

**When I console it shows the error as**

```
500 (Internal Server Error)
```

**How to update the values in laravel session array.**

Comment: there is no key named `quan` in your $cart

Comment: oh yes...thank you...

Comment: @bhucho i tried with correction but it show same error again. is my incrementing code is correct?

Comment: why are you not doing it like this `if($cart[$key]['id'] == $id){
                    $value['qty'] = $qty_up; $value['ind_tot'] = $ind_tot;
                }` and then after foreach `Session::set('cart_sess', $cart);`

Comment: Did you set APP_DEBUG=true in your .env? Then you can see the stack trace, not just a 500

Comment: @anders yes , APP_DEBUG=true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this

```
public function increment(Request $request){
        $id = $request->id;
        $rate = $request->rate;
        $qty = $request->qty;
        $ind_tot = $request->ind_tot;
        $input = $request->all();
        $qty_up = $qty+1;
        $ind_tot = $ind_tot+$rate;
        if($request->session()->has('cart_sess')){
            $cart = $request->session()->get('cart_sess');
            foreach ($cart as $key => $value){
                if($cart[$key]['id'] == $id){
                    $value['qty'] = $qty_up; 
                    $value['ind_tot'] = $ind_tot;
                }
            }
        }
        $request->session()->put('cart_sess', $cart);
        return response()->json($qty_up, 200);
    }
```

Comment: Im using Laravel 7, now its show new error that Call to undefined method Illuminate\Session\Store::set()

Comment: edited answer, laravel 7 uses put instead of set see here https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/session#storing-data

Comment: yes i got it bhucho... thank you sooooooooooo much i struct with this for more than a week, im new to laravel thank you again bhucho

Comment: or you can just change `Session::set()` to `Session::put()`